# Logisim Help - Using Custom D Flip Flop

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, logisim

I am trying to create a D Flip Flop to use in a bidirectional 4-bit shift register, using Logisim. However, when using my D flip flop the shift register acts just as a normal register setting the bit for all 4 D flip-flops outputs instead of one by one. It works properly when using the D flip-flop provided by Logisim but I am wondering how to achieve this using my own D Flip-Flop.

This is the design of my D Flip Flop
[image: This is the design of my D Flip Flop]

And this is the shift register (with the boxes representing the D Flip Flop)
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is a latch, not a flip-flop. The output will keep following the input as long as the clock is high. A flip-flop will not do that.

Comment: Unfortunately, there was no way to pass the clock output straight into the subcircuit so the latch was a workaround.

Comment: what...........?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

D flip-flop provided by Logisim which you used for simulation was a positive edge-triggered D Flip-Flop. While what you have designed is a level-sensitive D latch.

You have to cascade two of those D latches in master-slave configuration to obtain a positive edge-triggered D Flip-Flop.
[image]

[reference: Flip-Flops Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics))

Comment: For a rising-edge detector you can use the same configuration as the upper diagram, but put the not-gate on the other enable-pin.

Answer (score 1):

Shorten your clock pulse so that it is gone by the time the output data from one flip flop reaches the D input of the next. At the moment, with a long clock high time, when the new data arrives at a D input it is transferred straight through the flip flop and on to the next because the clock is still high.

This is a technique for producing a very short clock pulse, the duration of which is shorter than the time taken for the data to transition through the stage.

[image: D type flip flop]

Comment: Unfortunately, even of you set the clock to `Ton` to 1 tick and `Toff` to 31 ticks, it still doesn't work. I suspect it calculates differently the states for the builtin D flip flop.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  yes, latches are different from flipflops.

Comment: @user253751 True, but in real life you might get away with the inherent delays (also why you posted your answer). One of the reasons why I called it "concoction".