# Apparently correct D-flipflop implementation breaking my circuit. When using built-in D-flipflop, the circuit operates correctly

Tags: oscillation, logisim

I need to design a simple 4-way traffic controller for an assignment.
Traffic is from Road 1, Road 2 and Road 3 (see diagram below). If there is traffic on road 1 only, road 1's traffic light stays green and the other roads stay red. Similarly for the other roads.
If traffic on more than one road, then the green lights alternate.

[image: the three traffic light signals]

The specifications say that I need to use a d-flip flop with asynchronous clear for the sequential circuit part.

I have already designed the circuit. When using the built-in Logisim D flip-flop, the circuit operation is correct.

[image: example operation when there is traffic on road 1 only]

The assignment however requires us to implement the D flip-flop ourselves.
I made a d flip flop as a subcircuit, and it seems to be working fine (outputs as expected)

[image: my dflipflop implementation]
However, when using my d flip flop in the main circuit, it works when only one of the inputs is asserted.
[image]

If more than one input is 1, instead of alternating red and green lights, I get an "oscillation apparent"
[image]

The error definitely seems to be with my d flip flop implementation, and more specifically the asynchronous inputs, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Let me know if I need to provide more information. Any help much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: [Duplicate/similar](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/532999/95619).

Comment: As mentioned in the answers it is not a flip flop. You may want to have a look at [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21887/difference-between-latch-and-flip-flop) as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Logisim Help - Using Custom D Flip Flop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/532999/logisim-help-using-custom-d-flip-flop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your implementation is a D latch not a D flipflop. A D flip flop is made up of two latches in series using an inverted clock on the last latch.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I didn't know there was a difference between the two! Read up on race conditions and all, and this master-slave setup seems to overcome this problem, right? Also, another question, the input to the lower left-most nand gate is the output of the upper left-most nand gate. Why is that so? Why not complement D and feed as input to the lower nand gate? Would this also work?

Comment: Yes it would. This solution this solution saves that gate.